# VBA Macro that returns a list of items that meet criteria

Tags: vba, excel

### I am trying to create a UserForm in Excel 2010/2013 that will look through a list of items and return a complete list based on a number I provide.

Here's what the list would look like: **[See Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXNnt.jpg)** (image hosted on Imgur)

A Here's a snippit in case the image won't load...

Location ----- Title ----- Days Past
A2: 0001 | B2: Movie 1 | C2: 32
A3: 0001 | B3: Movie 2 | C3: 18
A4: 0001 | B4: Movie 3 | C4: 10
A5: 0004 | B5: Movie 1 | C5: 32
A6: 0007 | B6: Movie 1 | C6: 32
A7: 0007 | B7: Movie 2 | C7: 18
A8: 0009 | B8: Movie 1 | C8: 32
A9: 0014 | B9: Movie 1 | C9: 32

I have a userform that will return the first item in the list, but not the complete list. Ideally I would like to stay away from using a list box, mainly because the goal is to be able to copy the items in the full list.

I have tried the Index() formula but I don't know how to transfer that to work in VBA.
Any help you have would be great!

Comment: I am not getting the image to load but I have developed similar UserForms and Macros to handle exactly what you are dealing with. If you can be a bit more specific or try a photo reupload I would be happy to help.

Comment: I feel like a ListBox is *exactly* what you want for this sort of thing. You could of course use a textbox or a label or some other control and simply split/parse the values from the Range array.  But A ListBox seems like it is designed for what yuo need. Pleas add to your explanation to clarify?

Comment: @MoietyDesign Hi! I added a text example of what I am basically using it for.

Comment: @DavidZemens I understand a list box would work, but I am wanting them to show as a full list, not have to select each line to view them. If I have this wrong and there's another option, please let me know! I am still working on fully understanding VBA and all of the capabilities of it!

Comment: @Brady and you want it to only show the first item in the list? By first item do you want that by `Location`, `Title` etc... What are you distinguishing for the list?

Comment: *I am wanting them to show as a full list*  **<<** What does this mean? Can you describe *why* you think that a listbox *doesn't* "display a full list"?  Also, please **edit your question** to include the code that populates your listbox, so that we can recommend solution(s).

Comment: @MoietyDesign  I am basically wanting this: I have a userform that has TextBox1 that I put a location number in and then click search. After that, it will populate a list of all of the "Titles" that have that location's number. If possible, I would like it to put a comma and put the days past as well (but that can be sacrificed if needed).

Comment: @DavidZemens   Sorry! I am not trying to make this as complicated as it is coming out. The only other time I've used a list box was for a previous project that basically showed series of row numbers and when you clicked the row number, it would tell you the details about that entry. That's what I am avoiding here. I want to eliminate the extra step of clicking the number to see the data. As for the code, right now I just have a VLookup function that returns just the first cell's information. If I could loop it to show all of the details, that would be awesome, but I'm not sure if it's possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written this for you, which if your location values are given in the `A` column, Titles in the `B` and Days Past in the `C` this should work:

```
Private Sub SUBMITBUTTON_Click()

Dim counter As Integer, TITLELIST(), DAYSPAST(), fullString As String
fullString = ""

If LOCATIONTEXTBOX.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please input a location"
    Exit Sub
End If

For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
    If Cell.Value = LOCATIONTEXTBOX.Text Then
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next

ReDim TITLELIST(counter)
ReDim DAYSPAST(counter)
counter = 0

For i = 1 To Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    If Cells(1, i).Value = LOCATIONTEXTBOX.Text Then
        TITLELIST(counter) = Cells(i, 2).Value
        DAYSPAST(counter) = Cells(i, 3).Value
        fullString = fullString & CStr(TITLELIST(counter)) & "," & CStr(DAYSPAST(counter)) & ","
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next

MsgBox fullString
Range("H8").Value = fullString

End Sub
```

If you change the names of SUBMITBUTTON and LOCATIONTEXTBOX then it should work in your userform.

Comment: You are awesome! After some tweaks to make it work with my workbook, it worked like a charm! You have no idea how grateful I am! I would vote you up, but apparently I don't have the reputation for that yet. Haha!